# RegEx getting script & parameters .. almost there

Tags: c#, regex, newline

I'm trying to parse a Powershell script for its functions and parameters. I am almost there, byt I am having troubles with newlines. The expression parses test2 to test6 fine but with test1 I cannot get it to work.

I could of course specify my clients do not use the first syntax, but there must be a way. Can someone point me in the right direction? FWIW: I'm using this in C#.

The regex I'm using is: "`function (\w*)\s*\{\s*param\((.*)\)\s*}`"

content testfile.ps1:

```
function test1    {
  param([string]$parm1, [int]$parm2,
    [bool]$parm3)}


function test2
{
    param([int]$parm2, [bool]$parm3)

}

function test3
{    param(blabla3)}

function test4 { param(blabla4) }
function test5 {param(blabla5)}
function test6{param(blabla6)}
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't show you code I'm guessing that you didn't tell the `Regex` object that newlines were allowed. You can do this with the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. This changes the behavior of the . expression to allow it to match against newline (\n). However, if you do your expression could match more than you want. Regular expressions are greedy and this `(.*)` will consume up to the last parenthesis in the file. You might want to try something like:

```
function (\w*)\s*\{\s*param\(([^)]*)\)\s*}
```

Comment: This looks good, but note that it doesn’t allow for extra whitespace after `function` or `param`:  

    `^\s*function\s*(\w*)\s*\{\s*param\s*\(([^)]*)\)`

  
I’ve also avoided capturing the rest of the function as it doesn’t look like you need it.

Comment: This indeed does the trick! Thanks! I had experimented with that option but that (.*) probably messed things up.

The only thing now is that is seems to create 3 groups instead of 2. There is always a space as the first group. I can eliminate those with a trailing `\s*` but I still do not get why that happens.

@ciaran-walsh: the `^` and `$` do not work. Maybe because it's a Singleline now?

Answer (score 0):

Is your regex in single line or multi-line match mode?

I think:

```
"^function (\w*)\s*\{\s*param\((.*)\)\s*}$"
```

might work in multi-line mode. I dont have [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) open available right now to test it.

Comment: It was multi-line mode. But as mentioned above, the start-of-line and end-of-line options do not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function (\w*).*?\{.*?[A-Za-z]+\((.*?)\).*?}
```

Enable multiline matching on "." as mentioned and use this. I tested against http://www.myregextester.com/ and it seemed to work.

I've replaced your `\s*` with `.*?`. This matches any character, non-greedy, until the next specified sequence.